# Forcing single threaded request handling with web.py

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, web.py

I'm using web.py framework. For debugging purposes, I'd like to force all requests to be handled by a single thread, or simulate such behaviour with a mutex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me suggest something like this, but it will lock only current application stack over your controller method.

```
import web
from threading import Lock

urls = ("/", "Index")


class Index:

    def GET(self):
        # This will be locked
        return "hello world"


def mutex_processor():
    mutex = Lock()

    def processor_func(handle):
        mutex.acquire()
        try:
            return handle()
        finally:
            mutex.release()
    return processor_func

app = web.application(urls, globals())

app.add_processor(mutex_processor())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

UPD: if you need to lock the whole application stack then you probably have to wrap `app.wsgifunc` with your own WSGI middleware. To get an idea check my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960295/changing-the-static-directory-path-in-webpy?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

To get things decently into a single thread debugging mode, the web.py app can be run with a single threaded WSGI server.

Such server is "almost" offered by web.py itself  as `web.httpserver.runbasic()` which uses Python's builtin `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` - but also `SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn` .
This `ThreadingMixIn` however can be blocked by something like this:

```py
# single threaded execution of web.py app

app = web.application(urls, globals())

# suppress ThreadingMixIn in web.httpserver.runbasic()
import SocketServer
class NoThreadingMixIn:
    pass
assert SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn
SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn = NoThreadingMixIn

web.httpserver.runbasic(app.wsgifunc())
```

Or you could replicate the rather short `web.httpserver.runbasic()` code.