# web.py - server and simultaneous socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, sqlite, web.py

I'm working on an application in web.py which can send commands to a device through a website with buttons.

I know which buttons are pushed on my website and I get some parameters back in my python serverprogram. Python-program -> gets the basic commands out of an SQLite-database -> adds the received parameters. But I need to simultaneously set up a connection with the remote device through Ethernet (simple socket connection) to send these commands to the device. That's where I got stuck.

So I have the website working correctly, I also have a small seperate terminal program written to just make connection with the device and with a simple terminal interface to send commands. So basically I have the 2 major parts of the program working, but not simultaneously and I can't figure out how to fit them together.

I have been reading through some information to let the webserver run in a separate thread or maybe I have to connect and close the socket connection with the device each time I get information (command/parameters) from the website? Can somebody push me somewhat in the right direction?

NB: the server is running on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: i dont know how widespread the wall-of-text fetish is. perhaps some structure would help.

Comment: You really need to format this better, separate paragraphs. Nobody wants to read such a massive block of text. Also, provide code examples where you can - it'll help us to help you faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem appears to be caused by socket connection not being thread-safe.

Each request to web.py server runs in its own thread, and if you want to access socket connection to your device, then you have to use locks or manage connection pool, if your device supports multiple connections.

To force web.py running in single thread mode please see the following answer:

[Forcing single threaded request handling with web.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270257/forcing-single-threaded-request-handling-with-web-py)

Note that you don't have to lock all requests (as in that answer) and may put lock only on the part of the code where connection is used.