# serving static file not from /static in webpy

Tags: file, static, web.py, serving

Is there a way of serving static files (images) not from the /static folder in webpy? What I would like to do is show images that are scattered in various directories, and moving all of them to /static is really not an option. If it is not feasible in webpy, are there any other python web frameworks that would do this?

Thanks,

v923z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it when deploying your web.app under different webserver. But if you want to set static path in web.py development server then you'll have to patch webpy's  static middleware or write your own. Please check my answer to the same question here: [Changing the static directory path in webpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960295/changing-the-static-directory-path-in-webpy?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, Andrey! So, if I understand you correctly, if I don't want to use middleware, then I would have to run webpy through apache. But in the middleware, can I set multiple static folders? As I said in the OP, I would like to serve images scattered in separate folders, so it would not be enough, if I could set a single static folder.

Comment: Yes, because web.py doesn't have this setting, "/static" is hardcoded here in the sources: https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/httpserver.py#L261

Comment: But can I, at least, have subfolders in /static? Since this is for local use only, I could live with that. But I couldn't figure out how to serve images from /static/im_dir1/, /static/im_dir2/, etc.

Comment: Sure, any link to a file inside /static should work. Directory indexes don't work.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that works now. So, I presume, the simplest workaround is, if I just map /static to my /photos/ directory using the middleware class. Thanks for the help!